# $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated

Tags: hadoop, warnings, deprecated

I started a hadoop cluster.
I get this warning message: `$HADOOP_HOME is deprecated`

I already add `export HADOOP_HOME_WARN_SUPPRESS="TRUE"` into `hadoop-env.sh`
When I started the cluster, I do not see any more warning message.
However, When I run `hadoop dfsadmin -report`, It shows again.

Comment: You should select an answer. May I suggest @devesh chanchlani's, below? It worked for me.

Answer (score 53):

in your .bashrc file, replace the "HADOOP_HOME" variable with "HADOOP_PREFIX" variable, and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

A  was opened for such issue and was fixed on version 0.20.204.0. However a similar [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7816) was opened on 0.20.205.0 and was fixed on 1.0. Please check your version to see if the fix is included.

Answer (score 2):

And now, `HADOOP_PREFIX` is being [deprecated](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11393), [HADOOP_HOME is returning](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11393).

Answer (score 0):

Replace HADOOP_HOME with HADOOP_PREFIX variable in the file where u have declared all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

My teacher tell me to use `HADOOP_INSTALL` instead of `HADOOP_HOME`.