# Cloudera CDH VM default HADOOP_HOME Location

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

What is the default HADOOP_HOME location in Cloudera CDH4 VM.

echo $HADOOP_HOME returns blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/lib/hadoop` is the default `HADOOP_HOME` in CDH4.

Regarding deprecation, it appears `HADOOP_PREFIX` is the replacement for `HADOOP_HOME`:

[$HADOOP_HOME is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286983/hadoop-home-is-deprecated)

I believe `HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` is only used for the map reduce infrastructure, if you are using HDFS directly, then you probably want `HADOOP_PREFIX`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to echo : HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME .
AFAIK, HADOOP_HOME is deprecated and HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is the new one for MapReduce1 and MapReduce2.