# Writing Spark RDD as Gzipped file in Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an output RDD in my spark code written in python. I want to save it in Amazon S3 as gzipped file. I have tried following functions.
The below function correctly saves the output rdd in s3 but not in gzipped format.

```
output_rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3://<name-of-bucket>/")
```

The below function returns error::  TypeError: saveAsHadoopFile() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

```
output_rdd.saveAsHadoopFile("s3://<name-of-bucket>/", 
                        compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec"
                       )
```

Please guide me with the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the output format as well.

Try this:

```
output_rdd.saveAsHadoopFile("s3://<name-of-bucket>/", "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat", compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
```

You can use any of the Hadoop-supported compression codecs:

- gzip: 
  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
- bzip2:
  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec
- LZO:
  com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec

Comment: Not related to the asked question directly, but you may also wanna consider using s3a or s3n for faster and huge volume writes. [reference| http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356041/technically-what-is-the-difference-between-s3n-s3a-and-s3]