# Spark performance is not enhancing

Tags: apache-spark, avro, apache-zeppelin

I am using **Zeppelin** to read avro files of size in GBs and have records in billions. I have tried with **2** instances and **7** instances on **AWS EMR**, but the performance seems equal. With **7** instances it is still taking alot of times. The code is:

```
val snowball = spark.read.avro(snowBallUrl + folder + prefix + "*.avro")
val prod = spark.read.avro(prodUrl + folder + prefix + "*.avro")

snowball.persist()
prod.persist()

val snowballCount = snowball.count()
val prodCount = prod.count()

val u = snowball.union(prod)  

Output:
snowballCount: Long = 13537690
prodCount: Long = 193885314
```

And the resources can be seen here:

[image]

The **spark.executor.cores** is set to **1**. If i try to change this number, the **Zeppelin** doesn't work and **spark context** shutdown. It would be great, if someone can hint a bit to improve the performance.

Edit:
I checked how many partitions it created:

```
snowball.rdd.partitions.size
prod.rdd.partitions.size
u.rdd.partitions.size

res21: Int = 55
res22: Int = 737
res23: Int = 792
```

Comment: Can you check how many actual files do you have? I have a feeling that this number is above `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I had 2 3GB files and roughly 300 250MB files. This error comes up because the partition size exceeds this limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query in Spark/scala Size exceeds Integer.MAX\_VALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247630/sql-query-in-spark-scala-size-exceeds-integer-max-value)

Comment: @philantrovert already pointed you to the root of the problem `No Spark shuffle block can be larger than 2GB (Integer.MAX_VALUE bytes) so you need more / smaller partitions.` Have you tried to increase the number of partitions on the RDD "u" using the `repartition` function?

Comment: @jose.goncabel Could you please describe, how can I define the repartition strategy depending on the size? If the size is in GB then repartitioning worth but if size is in MB and small then repartitioning doesnt worth. Moreover, I don't know how to get the size of the dataframe at runtime to do the repartitioning.

Comment: why do you use `persist` whereas your data have not been modified ?

Comment: @Setop I was just testing it. Because at first I use count. And after that in union, it will recompute the data frame, so i was checking whether persist will improve the performance or not.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed ok. Another way to ask : do you really need to count or is union the most important part of the process ?

Comment: @Setop Union is the most important task. Actually Im merging 2 different dataframes of around 90GBs and removing duplicates from them.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed, removing duplicates is not a process that scales very well. Maybe you can help it by providing a hash function. But not sure how.

Comment: @Setop hash function will not work i guess. Because the ids are hashed and it will create a single partition for one id.

Comment: First, you need to check the spark UI, how many executors you allocated, and how many tasks for each stage.