# How to load objects from S3 bucket into Spark in RStudio?

Tags: r, apache-spark, amazon-s3, sparklyr, s3-bucket

The Object in the S3 bucket is 5.3 GB size. In order to convert object into data, I used `get_object("link to bucket path")`. But this leads to memory issues.

So, I installed Spark 2.3.0 in RStudio and trying to load this object directly into Spark but the command to load object directly into spark is not known.
`library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")`

If I convert the object into a readable data type (such as data.frame/tbl in R) I would use `copy_to` to transfer the data into spark from R as below:

## Copy data to Spark

`spark_tbl <- copy_to(spark_conn,data)`

I was wondering how can convert the object inside spark ?

relevant links would be

1. https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/issues/170
2. [Sparklyr connection to S3 bucket throwing up error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190188/sparklyr-connection-to-s3-bucket-throwing-up-error)

Any guidance would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by convert?

Comment: convert the object type to data. So that I can use it as data.frame or tibble in R. Currently, the object is not readable within R unless it it converted into any kind of data.frame

Comment: `get_object` returns a `list` if I am not mistaken. We have no way to tell how it looks like or what output you expect. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution.

I was trying to read the csv file which is 5.3 GB from S3 bucket. But Since R is single-threaded, it was giving memory issues (IO exceptions).

However, the solution is to load sparklyr in R (library(sparklyr)) and hence now all the cores in the computer will be utilized.

get_object("link to bucket path") can be replaced by
spark_read_csv("link to bucket path"). Since RStudio uses all cores, we have no memory issues.

Also, depending on the file extension, you can change the functions: 
´spark_load_table, spark_read_jdbc, spark_read_json, spark_read_libsvm, spark_read_parquet, spark_read_source, spark_read_table, spark_read_text, spark_save_table, spark_write_csv, spark_write_jdbc, spark_write_json, spark_write_parquet, spark_write_source, spark_write_table, spark_write_text´