# Read CSV file from AWS S3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an EC2 instance running pyspark and I'm able to connect to it (ssh) and run interactive code within a Jupyter Notebook.

I have a S3 bucket with a csv file that I want to read, when I attempt to read it with:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename.csv')
```

Which throws a long Python error message and then something related to:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o131.csv.

Answer (score 1):

Specify S3 path along with access key and secret key as following:

```
's3n://<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>:<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>@my.bucket/folder/input_data.csv'
```

Comment: Changing it does not fix the issue. Getting the same error, if I move my file to the EC2 directory I'm able to read it without passing users and pwd information

Answer (score 0):

Access key-related information can be introduced in the typical username + password manner for URLs. As a rule, the access protocol should be `s3a`, the successor to `s3n` (see [Technically what is the difference between s3n, s3a and s3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356041/technically-what-is-the-difference-between-s3n-s3a-and-s3)). Putting this together, you get

```
spark.read.csv("s3a://<AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>:<AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>@bucketname/filename.csv")
```

As an aside, some Spark execution environments, e.g., Databricks, allow S3 buckets to be mounted as part of the file system. You can do the same when you build a cluster using something like [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse).

Comment: Changing it does not fix the issue. Getting the same error, if I move my file to the EC2 directory I'm able to read it without passing users and pwd information

Comment: Sure, an EC2 volume typically has a normal file system so you can read directly from it. It's rather difficult to diagnose your issue without a ton more information, e.g., roles, permissions, complete code, full stack traces, etc. The answer above is how Spark accesses S3 without mounting. If it's not working for you, it's a configuration/permissions issue.