# How to read and repartition a large dataset from one s3 location to another using spark, s3Distcp & aws EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, s3distcp

I am trying to move data in s3 which is partitioned on a date string at rest(source) to another location where it is partitioned at rest (destination) as year=yyyy/month=mm/day=dd/

While I am able to read the entire source location data in Spark and partition it in the destination format in tmp hdfs, the s3DistCp fails to copy this from hdfs to s3.
It fails with OutOnMemory error.

I am trying to write close to 2 million small files (20KB each)

My s3Distcp is running with the following args
`sudo -H -u hadoop nice -10 bash -c "if hdfs dfs -test -d hdfs:///<source_path>; then /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/s3-dist-cp.jar -libjars /usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/ -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=30 -Dmapreduce.child.java.opts=Xmx2048m --src hdfs:///<source_path> --dest s3a://<destination_path> --s3ServerSideEncryption;fi"`

It fails with

````
[2020-08-06 14:23:36,038] {bash_operator.py:126} INFO - # java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[2020-08-06 14:23:36,038] {bash_operator.py:126} INFO - # -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"```

The emr cluster I am running this is 
"master_instance_type": "r5d.8xlarge",
"core_instance_type": "r5.2xlarge",
"core_instance_count": "8",
"task_instance_types": [ "r5.2xlarge","m5.4xlarge"],
"task_instance_count": "1000"

Any suggestions what I could increase configurations on s3Distcp for it to be able to copy this without running out of memory?
````

Comment: Can you try `s3://` instead of `s3a://` as EMR doesn’t support `s3a`. Please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33356421/7857701) for more detail.

Also why aren’t you using [s3DistCp CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html)? Thats also available on EMR. No need to use `hadoop jar <cmd>`

Comment: This is being used as one if the many stages so s3DistCp cli is not an optimal option for us.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running this iteratively, for the said aws stack it was able to handle about 300K files in each iteration without OOM

Answer (score 0):

This is a `classic` case where you can use **multithread** `scheduling` capabilities of **Spark** by setting `spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR` and assigning `pools`

What you need to do is

- *create* your `list` of partitions beforehand
- Use this list as an iterable
- for each iterator from this list **trigger** one spark-job in different **pools**
- No need to use a differents3distcp

An example shown below:

**before doing spark-submit** =>

```
# Create a List of all *possible* partitions like this 
# Example S3 prefixes :
#     s3://my_bucket/my_table/year=2019/month=02/day=20
#    ...
#   ...
#      s3://my_bucket/my_table/year=2020/month=03/day=15
#     ...
#     ...
#     s3://my_bucket/my_table/year=2020/month=09/day=01

# WE SET `TARGET_PREFIX` as:
TARGET_PREFIX="s3://my_bucket/my_table"

# And Create a List ( till Day=nn part)
# By looping twice

# Increase loop numbers if partition is till hour
aws s3 ls "${TARGET_PREFIX}/"|grep PRE|awk '{print $2}'|while read year_part ;

do

full_year_part="${TARGET_PREFIX}/${year_part}";

aws s3 ls ${full_year_part}|grep PRE|awk '{print $2}'|while read month_part;

do

full_month_part=${full_year_part}${month_part};

aws s3 ls ${full_month_part}|grep PRE|awk -v pref=$full_month_part '{print pref$2}';

done;

done
```

Once Done, we run this script and save result in a file like this:
`bash build_year_month_day.sh > s3_<my_table_day_partition>_file.dat`

Now We are ready to run spark in *multithread*

The Spark code would need two things ( other than `scheduler.mode=FAIR`

`1. creating an iterator from the file created above # s3_<my_table_day_partition>_file.dat`

`2. sc.setLocalProperty`

See How It is Done .

*A*. We read The File in **our spark-app Python**

```
 year_month_date_index_file = "s3_<my_table_day_partition>_file.dat"
 with open(year_month_date_index_file, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
 content_iter = [(idx, c) for idx, c in enumerate(content.split("\n")) if c]
```

*B*.And use a **slice** of 100 Days to fire 100 threads:

```
    # Number of THREADS can be Increased or Decreased 
    strt = 0
    stp = 99
    while strt < len(content_iter):
        
        threads_lst = []
        path_slices = islice(content_iter, strt, stp)
        for s3path in path_slices:
            print("PROCESSING FOR PATH {}".format(s3path))
            pool_index = int(s3path[0]) # Spark needs a POOL ID
            my_addr = s3path[1]
            # CALLING `process_in_pool` in each thread
            agg_by_day_thread = threading.Thread(target=process_in_pool, args=(pool_index, <additional_args>)) # Pool_index is mandatory argument.
            agg_by_day_thread.start() # Start opf Thread
            threads_lst.append(agg_by_day_thread)
        
        for process in threads_lst:
            process.join() # Wait for All Threads To Finish
        
        strt = stp
        stp += 100
```

**Two Things to notice**
`path_slices = islice(content_iter, strt, stp)` **=>** returns slices of the size `(strt - stp)`

`pool_index = int(s3path[0])` **=>** the index of `content_iter`, we would use this to assign a pool id.

**Now The Meat of the code**

```
def process_in_pool(pool_id, <other_arguments>):
    sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool_id_{}".format(str(int(pool_id) % 100)))
```

As you see we want to **restrict** threads to **100** pools
So, we set `spark.scheduler.pool` as `pool_idex`%100
Write your actual Transformation/Action in this `**process_in_pool()** function

And once done, exit the function by **freeing** that pool
as

```
...
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", None)
return
```

**finally**
Run you spark-submit like

```
spark-submit \
-- Other options \
--conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR \
--other options \
my_spark_app.py
```

If **tuned** with correct executor/core/memory, you would see a **huge** performance gain.

Same can be done in `scala` with `concurrent.futures`
But that's for another day.