# Amazon EMR pyspark unable to read a JSON file

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, bigdata, amazon-emr

I am new to EMR and Bigdata,

We have an EMR step and that was working fine till last month, currently I am getting the below error.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1660495066893_0006/container_1660495066893_0006_01_000001/src.zip/src/source/Data_Extraction.py", line 59, in process_job_description
    df_job_desc = spark.read.schema(schema_jd).option('multiline',"true").json(self.filepath)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1660495066893_0006/container_1660495066893_0006_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 274, in json
    return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1660495066893_0006/container_1660495066893_0006_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1660495066893_0006/container_1660495066893_0006_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1660495066893_0006/container_1660495066893_0006_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o115.json.
: java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.list(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:421)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.listStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:654)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.listStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:625)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.listStatus(EmrFileSystem.java:473)
    at
```

these json files are presents in S3, I downloaded some of the files to reproduce the issue in local,
when I have smaller set of data, it is working fine, but in EMR im unable to reproduce.

also, I checked Application details of EMR for this step.

it says `undefined` status for status with the below details.

```
Details:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3285)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

spark session creation

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
spark_builder = (
        SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .config(conf=SparkConf())\
        .appName("test"))
spark = spark_builder.getOrCreate()
```

I am not sure, what went wrong suddenly with this step, please help.

Comment: Based on the errors , the problem , is your connectivity with S3 , example for s3 read can be found - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734268/java-io-ioexception-no-filesystem-for-scheme-s3

Comment: but my other steps are working fine which are also reading json from s3, I am using same procedure

Comment: Your AWS token might have expired

Comment: thanks, but we are not using tokens. we create spark session by spark context, and emr has permission to read s3, so it automatically reads

Comment: Can you update the question with how are you establishing the S3 connectivity

Comment: I updated the question, can you check

Comment: While I haven't run across this particular issue, I do have EMR jobs that ran fine for years until "serverless EMR" was released. We've seen a general degradation of EMR with tons of inexplicable failures since that release. We're abandoning EMR and going with our own kubernetes scripts as a result. So far it's faster, cheaper, and far more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Your error indicates a failed security protocol as suggested by various results from googling all pointing to throttling/rejecting incoming TLS connections. Given that this occurs in the context of a backoff strategy.

You can further try these suggestions for retrying with exponential backoff strategy - [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-emrfs-retry.html) and limiting your requests by utilising the AMID.

Additionally you can check you DNS [quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-limits) to check if that is not limiting anything or exhausting your quota

Further add your Application Environment to further check if an outdated version might be causing this-

- EMR Release version
- Spark Versions
- AWS SDK Version
- AMI [ Amazon Linux Machine Images ] versions
- Java & JVM Details
- Hadoop Details

Recommended Environment would be to use - `AMI 2.x` , `EMR - 5.3x` and the compatible SDKs towards the same [ Preferably AWSS3JavaClient 1.11x ]

More info about EMR releases can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html)

Additionally provide a clear snippet , how are you exactly reading your json files from S3 , are you doing it in an iterative fashion , 1 after the other or in bulk or batches

References used -

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2269
- [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake during web service communicaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245796/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh)
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1405

Answer (score 0):

From your error message: `...SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Remote host terminated the handshake`, seems like you've got  a security protocol that is not accepted by the host or the error indicates that the connection was closed on the service side before the SDK was able to perform handshake. **You should add a try/except block and add some delay between retrys, to handle those**

```
errors = 0
while errors < 5:
    try:
        df_job_desc = spark.read.schema(schema_jd).option('multiline',"true").json(self.filepath)
        errors = 0
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
        errors += 1
        pass
```

Comment: Can you provide example

Comment: just added edited to add an example

Comment: the variable `read` is meant to change once the read operation is successful (hence why it is `while not read`). However, this is an example, you need to apply it and test it on your own thing.

Comment: yes I applied to my solution, its a forever ending loop, everytime the same error throws, the step was running for more than  5 hours, so I stopped now

Comment: like I said, it was only an example, but I have edited to add a counter and retry a maximum of 5 times before exiting the while loop. You may also increase the delay, you may be blocked from making too many requests