# context.py:79: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I use PySpark in my system.
I got the warninig:  context.py:79: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead.

my script:

```
 scSpark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "./mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar").getOrCreate()
    sqlContext = SQLContext(scSpark)

    jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(hostname, jdbcPort, dbname)
    connectionProperties = {
        "user": username,
        "password": password
    }
    #df=scSpark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='bms_title', properties= connectionProperties)
    #df.show()


    df = scSpark.read.csv(data_file, header=True, sep=",", encoding='UTF-8').cache()
    df2 = df.first()

    df = df.exceptAll(scSpark.createDataFrame([df2]))

    df.createTempView("books")

    output = scSpark.sql('SELECT `Postgraduate Course` AS Postgraduate_Course FROM books'))
```

Why I got this warning as I have already used SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
How could I correct this warning?

Comment: Do you need `sqlContext = SQLContext(scSpark)`?

Comment: Yes, I do need sqlContext = SQLContext(scSpark)

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(scSpark)
```

to

```
sqlContext = scSpark.sparkContext
```

or even

```
sc = scSpark.sparkContext
```

SQLContext is deprecated. more details you can find here: [Difference between SparkContext, JavaSparkContext, SQLContext, and SparkSession?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802809/difference-between-sparkcontext-javasparkcontext-sqlcontext-and-sparksession)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this one:

```
scSpark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", 
"./mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar").getOrCreate()
```

to this:

```
scSpark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", 
"./mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

`.enableHiveSupport()` should fix it.

It also happened to me when I had `toPandas` in my code when I needed to convert the pyspark df to pandas df. In such a case, I tried to import the data from the beginning as pandas and not pyspark instead of converting later.