# Reading Files from S3 Bucket to PySpark Dataframe Boto3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3

How can I load a bunch of files from a S3 bucket into a single PySpark dataframe?  I'm running on an EMR instance. If the file is local, I can use the SparkContext textFile method. But when the file is on S3, how can I use boto3 to load multiple files of various types (CSV, JSON, ...) into a single dataframe for processing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark natively reads from S3 using Hadoop APIs, not Boto3. And `textFile` is for reading RDD, [not DataFrames](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader). Also do not try to load two different formats into a single dataframe as you won't be able to consistently parse them

I would suggest using

```
csvDf = spark.read.csv("s3a://path/to/files/*.csv")
jsonDf = spark.read.json("s3a://path/to/files/*.json")
```

And from there, you can filter and join the dataframes using SparkSQL.

Note: [JSON files need to contain single JSON objects each on their own line](http://jsonlines.org/)

Comment: You mean I shouldn't combine multiple file types into a single dataframe? What is the right way to combine data from multiple sources/types in the PySpark framework?

Comment: I'm getting a No FileSystem for scheme: s3 error. And I also tried s3n and s3a with similar errors.

Comment: To load multiple types, you need different parsers, as shown... You join or union the dataframes to get all your data together in a unified format. Regarding the errors, it should already work on EMR, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33787125/2308683

Comment: Turns out my conda installation on the EMR is using a different pyspark than what was installed.

Comment: Yeah, if your cluster already has Spark, you don't need Conda to manage it

Comment: I'm using Conda for managing versions of installed libraries for ML. I just had to export the PYSPARK_PYTHON variable to use the conda python.