# HDP 2.2 HDFS folder back-up from EC2 to S3 throws exception

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hadoop2, ambari

My cluster is Ambari Hortonworks(ambari-server-2.0.1-45) HDP 2.2:

I want to backup a hdfs folder onto AWS S3. I used following command:
hadoop distcp hdfs://internalip:8020/backup s3://AWS-ID:AWS-SECRET-KEY@BUCKET-NAME/DIRECTORY-NAME

I have tried following [How can I access S3/S3n from a local Hadoop 2.6 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029134/how-can-i-access-s3-s3n-from-a-local-hadoop-2-6-installation/29550279#29550279)

But I am still getting the following error:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2076)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.setup(CopyMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.execute(DistCp.java:175)
```

Comment: In java we can pass classpath as java -cp ... I want to run hadoop distcp giving classpath alongwith the hadoop distcp command. Is there a way to do it ?