# Some errors happen when loading data to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a Java program trying to load data to HDFS:

```
public class CopyFileToHDFS {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   try{
         Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

         String msg = "message1";
         String file = "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/user1/input.txt";
         FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(file), configuration);
         FSDataOutputStream outputStream = hdfs.create(new Path(file), true);
         outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
 }
}
```

When I run the program, it gives me an error:

```
    java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem not found
```

It looks like some configuration issues. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use "hdfs:///" instead of "hdfs://"

Answer (score 0):

Something is specifying that `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` includes S3. One possible cause is an old, stale META-INF file; see this [Spark bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10846).

If you're creating an uber-jar, it could be somewhere in there. If you can't find and eliminate the spec that's causing the problem, a work-around is to include AWS & Hadoop jars where the Spark driver/executors can find them; see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029134/how-can-i-access-s3-s3n-from-a-local-hadoop-2-6-installation).