# How can I read from S3 in pyspark running in local mode?

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am using PyCharm 2018.1 using Python 3.4 with Spark 2.3 installed via pip in a virtualenv.  There is no hadoop installation on the local host, so there is no Spark installation (thus no SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, etc.)

When I try this:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()\
    .setMaster("local")\
    .setAppName("pyspark-unittests")\
    .set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
inputFile = sparkContext.textFile("s3://somebucket/file.csv")
```

I get:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.partitions.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3
```

How can I read from s3 while running pyspark in local mode without a complete Hadoop install locally?

FWIW - this works great when I execute it on an EMR node in non-local mode.

The following does not work (same error, although it does resolve and download the dependancies):

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.1.0" pyspark-shell'
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()\
    .setMaster("local")\
    .setAppName("pyspark-unittests")\
    .set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
inputFile = sparkContext.textFile("s3://somebucket/file.csv")
```

Same (bad) results with:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars "/path/to/hadoop-aws-3.1.0.jar" pyspark-shell'
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()\
    .setMaster("local")\
    .setAppName("pyspark-unittests")\
    .set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
inputFile = sparkContext.textFile("s3://somebucket/file.csv")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access S3/S3n from a local Hadoop 2.6 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029134/how-can-i-access-s3-s3n-from-a-local-hadoop-2-6-installation)

Comment: There is no local Hadoop installation in this case - just Spark installed in the virtualenv via pip.

Comment: Try to use `s3a` [protocol](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/36339/spark-s3a-filesystem-client-from-hdp-to-access-s3.html):

  inputFile = sparkContext.textFile("s3a://somebucket/file.csv")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So Glennie's answer was close but not what would work in your case. The key thing was to select the right version of the dependencies. If you look at the virtual environment

[image: Jars]

Everything points to one version which `2.7.3`, which what you also need to use

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3" pyspark-shell'
```

You should verify the version that your installation using by checking the path `venv/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/jars` inside your project's virtual env

And after that you can use `s3a` by default or `s3` by defining the handler class for the same

```
# Only needed if you use s3://
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', 'awsKey')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', 'awsSecret')
s3File = sc.textFile("s3a://myrepo/test.csv")

print(s3File.count())
print(s3File.id())
```

And the output is below

[image: OutputSpark]

Comment: What's the hierarchy in the Project pane to get to that "hadoop-common-2.7.3"?  (So that I can check and make sure I have the same one).

Comment: On my laptop the relative path in environment is `venv/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/jars`

Comment: Very close.  I'm now getting "com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain."  We don't support permanent awsKey/awsSecret pairs, so I need to figure out how to get this to work with either a sessionToken or com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider, where I'll have a session token in my creds file.  Any hints?  Or want me to open another question on that one?

Comment: I think that is a new problem, so best sorted out on a new question. You post the link here and will try and help

Comment: Here's the new question - thanks for any help you can give!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242843/how-do-i-use-an-aws-sessiontoken-to-read-from-s3-in-pyspark

Comment: Here's another one I would love your help with :):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243130/how-do-i-update-the-java-keystore-used-by-pyspark-running-in-pycharm-on-mac

Comment: should be `"fs.s3a.impl"` instead of `"fs.s3.impl"`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `s3a` protocol when accessing S3 locally. Make sure you add your key and secret to the `SparkContext` first. Like this:

```
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', 'awsKey')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', 'awsSecret')

inputFile = sparkContext.textFile("s3a://somebucket/file.csv")
```

Comment: With the --packages in the question, this gets closer.....   I now get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities".  Seems like I'm still missing some dependencies.

Comment: If I also add "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.1.0" to the packages, I get "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.reloadExistingConfigurations()"....so probably just need to find the correct version of hadoop-common (I think)

Answer (score 1):

preparation:

Add following lines to your spark config file, for my local pyspark, it is `/usr/local/spark/conf/spark-default.conf`

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=<your access key>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=<your secret key>
```

python file content:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os

from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = "/usr/bin/python3"
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = "/usr/bin/python3"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("read_s3").setMaster("local[2]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    my_s3_file3 = sc.textFile("s3a://store-test-1/test-file")
    print("file count:", my_s3_file3.count())
```

commit:

```
spark-submit --master local \
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,\
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,\
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.3 \
<path to the py file above>
```