# How do I use an AWS SessionToken to read from S3 in pyspark?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark

Assume I'm doing this:

```
import os os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3" pyspark-shell' from pyspark import SparkConf from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

conf = SparkConf() \
        .setMaster("local[2]") \
        .setAppName("pyspark-unittests") \
        .set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
s3File = sc.textFile("s3a://myrepo/test.csv")
print(s3File.count())
print(s3File.id())
```

I know that, in theory, I can do this before the 'sc.textFile(...)' call to set my credentials:

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.access.key', 'awsKey')
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.s3a.secret.key', 'awsSecret')
```

However; I don't have a key/secret pair, instead, I have a key/secret/token triplet (they are temporary credentials that are refreshed periodically via AssumeRole....see here for details on getting those credentials: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html)

How can I use the triplet to authenticate to AWS S3, rather than just the key and secret?

My preference would be to use `com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider` as the credentials provider (and have the key/secret/token in ~/.aws/credentials).  I would settle for providing them on the command line or hard coded.

If I try this (with my credentials in ~/.aws/credentials):

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider")
```

I still get this:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.partitions.
: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

How can I either load credentials from ~/.aws/credentials or otherwise use a SessionToken?

Comment: You need to `export AWS_PROFILE=<profile_name>` before starting Spark so that `ProfileCredentialsProvider` knows what AWS profile to pull credentials from. This assumes that you are storing your temporary credentials under a named profile in your AWS credentials file.

Answer (score 12):

I don't see `com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider` in the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html). There is, however, `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider` which allows you to use the key and secret along with `fs.s3a.session.token` which is where the token should go.

The instructions on that page say:

> To authenticate with these:
>
> 1. Declare `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider` as the provider.
> 2. Set the session key in the property `fs.s3a.session.token`, **and the access and secret key properties** to those of this temporary session.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <property>
>   <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>
>   <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider</value>
> </property>
>
> <property>
>   <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
>   <value>SESSION-ACCESS-KEY</value>
> </property>
>
> <property>
>   <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
>   <value>SESSION-SECRET-KEY</value>
> </property>
>
> <property>
>   <name>fs.s3a.session.token</name>
>   <value>SECRET-SESSION-TOKEN</value>
> </property>
> ```

Comment: `ProfileCredentialsProvider` is undocumented but does indeed work. I've filed [HADOOP-16930](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16930) to fill in the missing documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If your current AWS role is allowed to assume the cross-account role, you can use [boto3](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/) to get temporary session credentials:

```py
import boto3

role_session_name = "test-s3-read"
role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/crossaccount-role"
duration_seconds = 60*15 # durations of the session in seconds

credentials = boto3.client("sts").assume_role(
    RoleArn=role_arn,
    RoleSessionName=role_session_name,
    DurationSeconds=duration_seconds
)['Credentials']
```

> How can I use the triplet to authenticate to AWS S3, rather than just the key and secret?

You can pass the `AccessKeyId`, `SecretAccessKey` and `SessionToken` to Spark like this:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("test bucket access") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", credentials['AccessKeyId']) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", credentials['SecretAccessKey']) \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token", credentials['SessionToken']) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Verified with Spark 2.4.4 and it might not work with older versions.