# Spark integration with S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

This is an old issue and I have solved it by follow the answer in this post:
[How can I access S3/S3n from a local Hadoop 2.6 installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029134/how-can-i-access-s3-s3n-from-a-local-hadoop-2-6-installation)

The answer from Kamil Sindi works for me, by adding packages in spark-shell option:

```
spark-shell --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.967,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0
```

When I type below command, it works.

```
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
scala> sc.textFile("s3://test/testdata.txt").foreach(println)
```

But when I add jars as below:

```
spark-shell --jars /tmp/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar , /tmp/aws-java-sdk-1.11.967.jar
```

an error throw as below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

Can any one tell me why adding jars doesn't work.
How can I solve this issue by adding jars as other answers suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. please use the bundle jar, which locates in

$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/

spark-shell --jars /data/workspace/files/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar,/data/workspace/files/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.563.jar